# Hitting "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used" error

Tags: winforms, ms-access

I am trying to write a Windows Form program on top of .NET 4.0 and accessing Microsoft Access Database. I can read and write with no problem but sometimes, I get this error:

> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

I tried to call this method (GetIDBasedonTeamName) with different inputs twice (on the same thread). The second time this is run, I got that error.

```
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    OleDbDataReader dr;

    public void OpenConnection(string name) // always call this method first in other methods to initialise connection
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
            + Application.StartupPath + "\\AppData\\" + name + ".mdb;";
        conn.Open();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.Parameters.Clear();
    }

public string GetIDBasedonTeamName(string teamName)
    {
        string toReturn = "";

        try
        {
            OpenConnection("form");
            comm.CommandText = "Select ID from TeamDetails WHERE TeamName=@teamName";
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("TeamName", teamName);

            dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                toReturn = dr[0].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
            string err = e.Message.ToString();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Exception happened on  dr = comm.ExecuteReader();.

The method that was calling this method have this 2 lines inside:

> ```
> InfoConfig.team1id = Convert.ToInt32(dbm.GetIDBasedonTeamName(cbxTeam1.Text));
> InfoConfig.team2id = Convert.ToInt32(dbm.GetIDBasedonTeamName(cbxTeam2.Text));
> ```

What could be the cause? I read around and they mentioned not to use different threads but it is the same thread here.

Thanks,
Guo Hong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the objects only once and storing them in fields in your class you should create, use and close the objects in your method. It is probably the `Close` you call in the end the method that releases the underlying COM objects giving you the exception on the second call.

Comment: So you are saying that I should do "OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(); OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection(); OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(); OleDbCommand cmd; OleDbDataReader dr;" and opening of connections in every methods?

Comment: @GuoHongLim: Yes, browsing the `OleDbConnection` documentation indicates that connection pooling is used. The proper pattern is then to create the necessary objects transiently in `using` statements like it is done in [the example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Building on Martin Liversage's answer:

```
public string GetIDBasedonTeamName(string teamName) {
    var connString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
        + Application.StartupPath + "\\AppData\\" + name + ".mdb;";
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString)) {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText="Select ID from TeamDetails WHERE TeamName = @teamName";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TeamName", teamName);
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (rdr.Read()) {
                    return (string)rdr["TeamName"];
                }
                //if no valid results will return null
            }
        }
    }
}
```